# Android - RecyclerView com espaços em branco entre os itens

Tags: android, android-layout

RecyclerView está mostrando grandes espaços em branco no layout.

Nota: Ao iniciar a rolagem para baixo, os items aparecem normalmente, mas ao voltar pra cima, começa a exibir grandes espaços em branco entre os itens.

Nota2: Todos os layouts pais (parents) estão com configurados com `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Eu vi essa solução no SOen, porém não resolveu no meu caso.

Nota3: Eu estou usando um CustomCursorAdapter junto com um CustomRecyclerViewAdapter. Talvez seja melhor ver meu [repositório completo](https://github.com/sshnakamoto/CardViewTest) do que apenas os trechos de código listados aqui.

O **código completo** está aqui:

- https://github.com/sshnakamoto/CardViewTest
- Demonstração do BUG:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**card_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_card_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/params_card_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Subtitle goes here"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_image" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/params_card_subtitle">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/item1_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item1_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.722" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.722" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item2" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item2_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.001" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.001" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item3" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item3_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item4" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item4_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item5" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/temp_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="26 °C" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="26 °C" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/expand_collapse_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_tableLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expand"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Subtitle goes here"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final int LOADER_ID = 0;
    private DbHelper helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ListCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Initialize */
        cursorAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, null);
        helper = new DbHelper(this);

        /* Setup Recycler */
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        /* Create dummy data to test */
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10){

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(NAME_COLUMN, String.valueOf(i));

            db.insert(TEST_TABLE, null, values);
            values.clear();
            i++;
        }
        return new CustomCursorLoader(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        cursorAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tive um problema semelhante, minha solução foi setar o layout raiz de cada item como wrap_content na altura, depois que fiz isso o problema resolveu.

Comment: @SamuelIves eu já fiz isso. E nada resolveu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nakamoto, dei uma olhada no seu código.
Consegui resolver colocando todo CardView dentro de uma exibição pai [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear?hl=pt-BR). Acredito que por se tratar de um Widget, este deve ser inserido dentro de um [Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=pt-BR) pai, com isso poderá definir a estrutura do layout e alinhar seus Widgets filho na vertical ou horizontal.

O código ficou assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_card_child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="16dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/params_card_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Subtitle goes here"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/test_image" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_tableLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/params_card_subtitle">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/item1_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item1_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.722" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item1_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.722" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item2" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item2_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.001" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item2_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.001" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item3" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item3_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item3_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item4" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item4_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item4_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0.000" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:text="item5" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/temp_table_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="2dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5_value_last"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="26 °C" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/test_table_item5_value_lastest"
                    style="@style/TableText"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="26 °C" />

            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/expand_collapse_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_tableLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/expand_collapse_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expand"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Subtitle goes here"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço.

Comment: muito obrigado. Você resolveu o problema e agora eu consigo te explicar o porquê. O responsável por esse bug é o atributo: `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`.

Se remover esse atributo do layout e a referencia dele no código `.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);` o erro some.

Muito obrigado por sua ajuda!

Comment: Esse commit deve esclarecer melhor, veja:
https://github.com/sshnakamoto/CardViewTest/commit/7ae19e39008a72e93d29064a544704fdb79ff0f1