# Android - Remover Espaço em Branco Entre os Itens da RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tenho um problema igual a este [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/301455/android-recyclerview-com-espa%C3%A7os-em-branco-entre-os-itens).
Estou usando o '**com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0**'. O XML é o seguinte, **activity_main.xml**, problema se encontra no **recyclerOverlay**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Convite Virtual"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ffffffff">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/framecontainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bgImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"

                    android:visibility="gone" />


                <com.selfcoderlab.birthday.photoframe.custom.TouchImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSize"


                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/rr_1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dip"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_1"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scaleType="matrix" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgOverlayView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

                        </FrameLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_img"
                        android:background="#ffffff">

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/main_img"
                        android:background="#ffffff">

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/main_img"
                        android:layout_width="380dp"
                        android:layout_height="500dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                         />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/main_img"
                        android:background="#ffffff" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"

                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_img"
                        android:background="#ffffff">

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <com.selfcoderlab.birthday.photoframe.custom.StickerBtn
                    android:id="@+id/sticker_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>


        </FrameLayout>


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="@integer/grid_columns"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:padding="16dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerOverlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#444"
            />

    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#444"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#283037"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgFrame"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_frame" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgGallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_gallery" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgOverlay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_overlay" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_sticker" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_text" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSave"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_save" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_share" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**sticker_category_item_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
mAdapter = new StickersAdapter(stickerArrayList);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
        MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerOverlay.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerOverlay.setAdapter(mAdapter);

public class StickersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<Sticker> StickersList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView imgSticker;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imgSticker = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgSticker);

            }
        }


        public StickersAdapter(List<Sticker> StickersList) {
            this.StickersList = StickersList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.sticker_category_item_view, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            Sticker = StickersList.get(position);

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(Sticker.stickerId).into(holder.imgSticker);
//            holder.imgSticker.setText(Sticker.getTitle());
            holder.imgSticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Sticker = StickersList.get(position);
                    imgOverlayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(Sticker.stickerId).into(imgOverlayView);
                    initShapeAlphaEffect();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return StickersList.size();
        }
    }
```

OBS: nas versões antigas o espaço em branco não aparece.
Mesmo utilizando o wrap_content os espaços em branco continuam na versão 28.0.0. Alguém pode me ajudar com essa questão?

Comment: Adicione o XML da linha da RecycleView na sua pergunta, por favor

Comment: Como está seu Item de dentro do RecycleView ? Alterando ele talvez possamos acertar talvez existe espaço entre os intens de dentro do sua RecycleView .

Comment: Ele está dentro de um FrameLayout que está dentro de um LinearLayout.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta um pequeno exemplo com código que replique a situação e que facilmente se possa usar para testar.

Comment: @Stéfano clique no editar abaixo da sua pergunta e adicione o XML completo de onde esta a RecycleView e o código do XML do item da RecycleView para que possamos analisar e te ajudar.

Comment: Resolvi o problema editando o item da RecycleView. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido mudando o layout do sticker_category_item_view.xml, usando apenas wrap_content, ficando assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imgSticker"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta colocar o recyclerView dentro de um CoordinatorLayout assim:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_generico"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentei de diversas formas o CoordinatorLayout, mas sem sucesso, o problema persiste.

Answer (score -1):

Ajuste o seu Recycler para pegar o espaço da tela disponível.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#444" />
```

Verifique i item modelo que você passa no Adapter, lá no Inflater, pois ele deve estar com as seguintes configuraçoes de tamnaho e altura:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Verifiquei, mas ainda sem sucesso.

Comment: Poderia retirar o LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, ou coloca-lo como VERTICAL?

Comment: Já tentei isso, ele fica com o mesmo problema no modo vertical.